# Recieved this error: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: graphql, react-hooks, hook, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I've a stepper form, that insert data using GraphQL/Apollo and React, of two different places.

Here are the code:

```
    export function ProjectStep({classes, nextStep}) {

      const {loading, error, data} = useUserQuery();
      const organizationsArray = _.get(data, "user.organizations");
      const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState("");
      const [organization, setOrganization] = useState("");
      const [createProject, appMutationResponse] = useappInsertMutation();
      const [createToken, tokenMutationResponse] = usetokenInsertMutation();
      const submitForm = () => {
        const variables = {name: projectName, orgId: organization, description: ""};
        createProject({variables});
      };

      const submitToken = () => {
        const variables = {
          enable: true,
          lastUsed: Date.now().toString(),
          appId: appMutationResponse.data.appInsert.id,
          orgId: appMutationResponse.data.appInsert.orgId,
        };
        createToken({variables});
      };

      if (appMutationResponse.data) {
        submitToken();
      }
}
```

The first insert is on:

```
const submitForm = () => {
            const variables = {name: projectName, orgId: organization, description: ""};
            createProject({variables});
          };
```

The second insert is on:

```
const submitToken = () => {
            const variables = {
              enable: true,
              lastUsed: Date.now().toString(),
              appId: appMutationResponse.data.appInsert.id,
              orgId: appMutationResponse.data.appInsert.orgId,
            };
            createToken({variables});
          };
```

These events are called in a button:

```
 <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type='button' onClick={submitForm}>
    Next
 </Button>
```

But, when i click on the button, i got this error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

When a go to my database, i see that 50 tokens are saved using this part of the code in a single call:

```
const submitToken = () => {
                const variables = {
                  enable: true,
                  lastUsed: Date.now().toString(),
                  appId: appMutationResponse.data.appInsert.id,
                  orgId: appMutationResponse.data.appInsert.orgId,
                };
                createToken({variables});
              };
```

I think that because i'm using a hook, i got a response and that response bring that error to me, the question is, why i'm saving and receiving in a single call, 50 tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written below code directly in render, so when the appMutationResponse.data is available if calls the `submitToken` function which triggers a re-render and then the function is called again causing an infinite loop.

```
if (appMutationResponse.data) {
   submitToken();
}
```

The solution is to put this code in useEffect and run it on data change

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (appMutationResponse.data) {
      submitToken();
   }
}, [appMutationResponse.data])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it resolved my problem. It was very enlightening.